# How do I arrange diagrams in pgfplots vertically with labels?

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

I have two ternary diagrams I put side by side on the same page using pgfplots.How can I arrange them vertically and as well label them?
An example of what I have is given below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
%           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sn,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sb,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
    ]

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };

    %\node[fill=white,draw] at (0.5,{sqrt(3)/2}) {$Sn$};

    %\node[fill=white,draw]  at (0,0) {$Sb$}; 

    %\node[fill=white,draw]  at (1,0) {$Bi$}; 

    %\legend{0.9, 0.8,0.7}
  \end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
%           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sb,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sn,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
  ]

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };

      %\node[fill=white,draw] at (0.5,{sqrt(3)/2}) {$Sn$};

      %\node[fill=white,draw]  at (0,0) {$Sb$}; 

      %\node[fill=white,draw]  at (1,0) {$Bi$}; 

      %\legend{0.9, 0.8,0.7}
    \end{ternaryaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a complete but [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that shows what you are doing and explain what you want to have as result?

Comment: You might have a look to the internal `groupplots` library: it is excellent for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a subfigure array

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}




\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
%           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sn,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sb,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
    ]

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };
  \end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{First Image}
\label{fig:a:first}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
%           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sb,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sn,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
  ]

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };

      %\node[fill=white,draw] at (0.5,{sqrt(3)/2}) {$Sn$};

      %\node[fill=white,draw]  at (0,0) {$Sb$}; 

      %\node[fill=white,draw]  at (1,0) {$Bi$}; 

      %\legend{0.9, 0.8,0.7}
    \end{ternaryaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Second Image}
\label{fig:a:second}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
%           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sn,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sb,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
    ]

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };
  \end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Third Image}
\label{fig:a:third}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Main caption}%
\label{fig:a}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Percusse.This really solved my problem.But what do I need to do if I want to insert C_{Bi} and a right arrow on each of the z-axis to indicate that Bi increases from left to right?

Answer (score 3):

I used `stackengine` package to stack the images.  First I did a `\savestack` to save each individual image.  Because it is not a `\long` command, I had to remove blank lines from your definition.  Then I used `\stackunder to put the labels 3pt (the default for shortstacks) below the images.  Finally, the labeled images were stacked under each other with a 15pt gap.

Note, if the label were to be longer than the width of the image, you could make the label text a `\parbox` of the image width.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-09-11]

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\savestack{\firstimage}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
%           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sn,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sb,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
    ]
    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };
    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };
    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };
    %\node[fill=white,draw] at (0.5,{sqrt(3)/2}) {$Sn$};
    %\node[fill=white,draw]  at (0,0) {$Sb$}; 
    %\node[fill=white,draw]  at (1,0) {$Bi$}; 
    %\legend{0.9, 0.8,0.7}
  \end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\savestack{\secondimage}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
%           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sb,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sn,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
  ]
    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };
    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };
    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };
      %\node[fill=white,draw] at (0.5,{sqrt(3)/2}) {$Sn$};
      %\node[fill=white,draw]  at (0,0) {$Sb$}; 
      %\node[fill=white,draw]  at (1,0) {$Bi$}; 
      %\legend{0.9, 0.8,0.7}
    \end{ternaryaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\stackunder[15pt]{%
  \stackunder{\firstimage}{Label for first image}%
}{%
  \stackunder{\secondimage}{Label for second image}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]